Lag function conversion into MS Access SQL
I am trying to convert the lag function to use in access-sql, which simply doesn't have the function. So I have a table A with columns Type (a,b or c),Decider (1 or 2), Dates and Values..I would like to create another column which simply shifts the values down one date, with the first value then being null.
I tried to use this thread below, but I guess I'm doing something wrong still:
Calculating difference in column value from one row to the next
My attempt was
select type, dates, values, 
   (select top 1 test.values 
    from test as m
    where m.dates < test.dates 
    group by test.type, test.values, test.dates
    order by test.values,test.dates desc
   ) as lag
from test
group by test.type, test.dates,test.values
order by test.dates


And what is the undesired result of your attempt?

select top 1 test.values  should that no be: select top 1 m.values , and also most other references to test.* (except for the one in the WHERE-clause)

Does this answer your question? Query for getting value from another record in same table and filter by difference greater than a gap threshold

Why are you including GROUP BY clause?

the part "select top 1 test.values
from test as m
where m.dates < test.dates
group by test.type, test.values, test.dates
order by test.values,test.dates desc
) as lag" I tried to export, because the whole thing was taking too long, but that also took for ever...how can I speed that up ?

To follow the linked solution, consider adding a WHERE condition for type column without any need of GROUP BY:
select [type], [dates], [values], 
   (select top 1 m.[values]
    from test as m
    where m.[dates] < test.[dates]
      and m.[type] = test.[type]
    order by m.[dates] desc
   ) as lag
from test
order by test.[type], test.[dates]

Alternatively, consider calculating a rank integer based on dates and store it in a new column. Then run a self join that uses new rank:
ALTER (to be run once or use Table Design)
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN date_rank INTEGER

UPDATE (to be run with every data change)
UPDATE test 
SET date_rank = DCount("*", "test", "[type]='" & test.[type] & "' AND [dates] >= #" & test.[dates] & "#")

SELECT (may not be fool-proof if dates tie)
SELECT t1.[type], t1.[dates], t1.[values], t2.[values] AS lag
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2
  ON t1.[type] = t2.[type]
  AND t1.[date_rank] = (t2.[date_rank] - 1)


Demo
Input Data

Subquery Solution

Rank + Join Solution


That works, but it's incredibly slow..I guess I have a lot of data, but are there ways to improve the performance?

Unfortunately, correlated subqueries can be agonizingly slow. What is nature of your data? Are date values sequential without gaps? Did you review VBA solution in link provided in my other comment?

Consider update for alternative solution.

My desired result is a column with the values shifted down by a date.. The date have gaps due to weekend and holidays

Understood. How did the alternative solution not work for you? After testing on random data and changing to a LEFT JOIN, the alternative solution exactly matches subquery solution with weekend gaps are handled. See screenshot of my demo.

Because the original way takes too long, I'm using the alter table update method now..I was just thinking..I have two factors, not just the type, can I still use this method?

What should the update do? As in my case it changes nothing in the column... It's all blank

Not sure. You have to carefully apply this solution to your actual data. Adjust column names as needed. Be sure data types are consistent like date/time, text, number. Add to the DLookup criteria and JOIN clause any additional factors.
